# Error when following instructions on "Hosting scopes"

Tags: bit.dev

I was trying to follow the instructions on hosting scopes (https://bit.dev/docs/scope/running-a-scope-server).

Commands entered:

```
docker run -it -p 4000:3000 bitcli/bit-server:latest
http://localhost:4000
bit remote add http://localhost:4000
```

I get the following error after the `bit remote add` command:
`error: scope not found at /Users/tdugger/development/bit`

There must be a step missing.  The browser page shown does say the following, but I'm not sure what that means.

```
Set "defaultScope": "remote-scope" in workspace.jsonc
file and export components here.
```

Thanks for your help.